# OpenCV and Visual C++

Tags: opencv

Is it possible to develop a custom application that can automatically change the settings of an IP camera using `OpenCV` with `Visual Studio 2010`?

Comment: This question is extremely vague, but yes.

Comment: To make this question more clear, what i need is to develop an application that can remotely configure the settings of my IP camera (1.3/2 Megapixel IP Bullet Camera). Ofcourse, the camera can be accessed through its IP in a browser. But I want a custom application using Visual C++ and openCV. N.B. I don't have any APIs that I can access to the camera setting though.

Comment: @Teddi then add it to the question descriptions itself. There is an "edit" button.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're asking does opencv have an interface for changing settings of ip cameras? Then no.

Are you sure there is no api for the camera? What does the webpage do when you save the settings? Send a post http request? Can you mimic that from your app? I'm sure there are rest clients available for http in c++.

If you are asking can opencv be used in visual studio then the answer is yes, quite nicely. Just add the includes to your VS include directory and lib to your lib directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it!
Peace be upon you!!